# Getting a random error: policy_enforced on most Google Apps when using OAuth 2

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

Since yesterday (October 2nd, 2014), there seem to be random errors when trying to access apps that use OAuth 2.

There are two problems:

1. We can't access the apps we use for our internal management.
2. Our clients that cannot login through their Google Apps sign in.

Here are the details of the error:

```
Request Details

from_login=1
response_type=code
scope=email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
access_type=online
redirect_uri=https://login.xero.com/SignIn/GoogleOAuthCallback
as=-5fc43****cf15779
pli=1
client_id=1061085901692-8vaq9******vuv2d2cro0eervp04j7a.apps.googleusercontent.com
authuser=0
hl=en
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I caused the same problem at OpenID Connect authentication, so  I had been made a query to Google Cloud Platform support.

Google updated to be not able to short name scope on Marketplace (without an announcement).
Now Google are considering to re-use short name scopes.
So We have to use long URL scope until Google corresponding to complete.

- email replace to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email or
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read
- profile replace to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
- openid replace to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me

Comment: thanks, we'll investigate. The strange thing is that some users under the same domain are not impacted

Comment: There is a mismatch between the scopes. Google tells in their documentation to use short names: `email`, `profile`. However when you register the app in the marketplace, they only allow `userinfo.email`, etc. We changed our code to use the long scope name, and everything works again. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

We are getting the same issue on our application. I have tested with using long names for scopes, but it did not help.

Also, it appears that the error only occurs from a Google Apps account. Regular Google account works fine.

The error does not occur for the users who have already given permission to the application.