# Google Apps OAuth2 authentication suddenly stopped working for many installs ("policy_enforced" error)

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

It seems that as of some time yesterday, single sign on with Google Apps (OAuth 2.0) stopped working completely for various Google Apps Marketplace installs.

Users get the following error when trying to log in:

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: policy_enforced
>
> Application: ....
>
> You can email the developer of this application at: .....
>
> Access denied by a security policy established by the Google Apps administrator of your organization. Please contact your administrator for further assistance.

What we found is *not* the cause:

- It's not a security policy change as the error says. It suddendly happens to many installs accross organizations, and none of them have made any changes.
- We haven't made any changes to the app, and searching Twitter reveals it's happening to multiple vendors.

What we have found these installs to have in common (so far), is that all of them are installs which were migrated from the Google Apps Marketplace V1 to GAMv2 recently. This happened months ago though and there have been no problems logging in since, the problem just appeared suddenly yesterday.

Is this a new bug in Google's authentication mechanism, any ideas what to do on fixing it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a random Error: policy\_enforced on most Google Apps when using OAuth 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175380/getting-a-random-error-policy-enforced-on-most-google-apps-when-using-oauth-2)

Answer (score 5):

We fixed the problem by replacing our auth scopes sent by our client:

'email' -> 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'

'profile' -> 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'

Comment: Related question & answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175380/getting-a-random-error-policy-enforced-on-most-google-apps-when-using-oauth-2